# Batch counting number of lines of text file without blank

Tags: batch-file, text-files, counting

I got two text files with different formats,let says i already have known there are 4 non-empty lines in the file,shown below (1st is valid, 2nd is invalid).

---

AAA

BBB

CCC

END

(Blank line)

(Blank line)

---

AAA

BBB

(Blank line)

CCC

END

---

Any "for loop" implementations/ways to distinguish 1st file has 4 non-empty lines which can tell it's valid and 2nd file has a extra blank line in the middle which can tell it's invalid.

Because i got a for loop code which can count non-empty line number,applying that code in this 2 files,it gives me line number=4,which i don't want it cause 2nd file is invalid format.
my for-loop code

```
        set count=0
        for /f %%a in (%text_file%) do set /a count+=1
        echo %count%
```

Any suggestion to identify two files by using lines-counting method?

Or you can tell me how to count the number of lines from starting until the critical string "END",Thanks in advance^.^

Comment: would it be sufficient to know, if `END` is in the fourth line?

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^END$" %text_file%') do set endline=%%i
echo %endline%
```

this finds the linenumber of the (last) line, that is equal to `<StartOfLine>END<EndOfLine>`

Comment: Stephan, it is a big helping hand.Thanks.

Comment: Your code really does what i want, 
Can you briefly recommend some places for learning such for-loop code ,i don't even know what "token" "delims" "%%i" means and why $ sign is put after END. So that i wont bother you guys next time? Any explanations?

Do you simply learn batch by typing "help for" in cmd?

Comment: Hey Stephan,a bug is found when ,in text file, i backspace the extra blank line right below }"END", and the text cursor land on right hand side of END,then i save the text file. Your code give endline as 0, it should be 4 right,how to fix it?

Comment: Oh, i find that removing the $ sign will work, lets try it out

Comment: `$` means "End of the line", `^` means "Start of the line". I put them in, just in case some "M**end**elson" got mentioned ;) Of course this will fail, if there is no line ending. As an alternative, you can search for `\<END\>", which means "the word 'END'"